# Uploading to a server through ssh

Tags: ssh, server

My boss has tasked me with working on a server. It is an aws server. I have minimal experience with servers. I need to upload apache Tomcat to the server from my mac through ssh. Can someone please explain, with serious detail, what commands specifically are used to upload the tomcat application to a ubuntu aws server through SSH in the mac terminal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install Tomcat on Ubuntu, just run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomcat tomcat7-docs tomcat7-admin tomcat7-examples
```

Navigate to `http://YOUR-IP-ADDRESS:8080/` to see if it worked.

Comment: download worked, computer running slow, taking a minute to access

Comment: Check your systems hardware resources by running `top` command.

Comment: okay i have a default page that loads at that adress how do i find tomcat otherwise

Comment: What do you mean be "Otherwise"? Do you want to know how to manage your webapps?

Comment: no i do not how to manage webpages. i mean by "otherwise" that if i go to that address i get the default page is there another way to see if it worked.

Comment: Check if the service is running: `service --status-all`

Comment: i have `apache2` but not `tomcat`